# Cordova-plugin-splashscreen clear cache for Android?

Tags: android, cordova, caching, ionic-framework

I installed cordova-plugin-splashscreen for the app I'm working on and ran the "ionic resources" command before having a properly sized splash.png.  I created a new splash.png but when I run "ionic resources" it is pulling the cached version off the Ionic server.  I've tried a lot of solutions I've found online with no luck.  How can I clear this cache?

Comment: Use IntelXDK to solve issue with plugins injection.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to get this working I created another Ionic app. Created a working splash screen in that app and then copied the files over.  That worked!  I also added more time to the splashscreendisplay in the config.xml file.  The annoying thing is it seems like this may be the solution for every time I need to adjust the splashscreen image.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Ionic. One way around is instead of creating a new project is to modify the file in any editor e.g. Resize, colour change etc. Re-saving the file would force ionic to re-upload the file. Hope this help.